# MKMapView, how to add custom views when I touch pinview?

Tags: mkmapview

MKMapView default, click on the pin view will appear with the title and subtitle of a small black box, but now I want to display the data more on a view. I want to display a customer view when I click on a pin view.

Has anyone done something similar? I have tried the following methods, but they did not work:

1. using a proxy access to the click event mapView: didSelectAnnotationView, but more than the delegate only supports ios4.x

   use tapgesture to capture the event, only support after ios3.2

   try to inherit MKMapView, found it impossible to get touch events.

Answer (score -1):

also possible duplicate of [MKMapView with custom MKAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007765/mkmapview-with-custom-mkannotation)
Here is how you can create a custom callout
http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

Wondering how to solve 
"3. try to inherit MKMapView, found it impossible to get touch events." on earlier than iOS4.x devices, here is how

- Subclass MKAnnotationView, shown below ( .h and .m files )

.h file

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface ClickableMapAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView {

        SEL pinClicked;
        id delegate;
    }

    @property(nonatomic, assign) SEL pinClicked;
    @property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ClickableMapAnnotationView.h"

@implementation ClickableMapAnnotationView

@synthesize pinClicked;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

    if ( delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:pinClicked] )
        [delegate performSelector:pinClicked withObject:self.annotation];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

- Then in UIViewController for mapView you need to set the ClickableAnnotation delegate and selector

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewParam viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {
    static NSString* PIN_RECYCLE_ID = @"pin";

```
if ( annotation == self.mapView.userLocation) // this is my location pin, skip
    return nil;

ClickableMapAnnotationView* pin = (ClickableMapAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: PIN_RECYCLE_ID];
if ( pin == nil ) {
    pin = [[[ClickableMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: PIN_RECYCLE_ID] autorelease];

    // wire, pin clicked functionality
    pin.delegate = self;
    pin.pinClicked = @selector(annotationViewClicked:);
```

....

```
-(void) annotationViewClicked:(id) sender {

   // map pin has been clicked

}
```